# JFrame in Eclipse with SQLite

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, windowbuilder

I found this example to connect with a SQLite database:

```
 try{

         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\pruebaSQLite\\dbTest.sqlite");
         System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos SQLite "); 
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }
```

it's working fine but I try to connect a JAVA application using it like this:

```
try {

                        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\LoginJava2\\myDB.sqlite");
                        PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("insert into hell(username,pssword) " +
                                "values ('"+tfUname.getText()+"','"+tfUpass.getText()+"')");
                        pstm.close();
                        con.close();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congrats, you have been registered succesfully");
                        RegisterWindow rw = new RegisterWindow();
                        rw.setVisible(false);
                        pack();
                        dispose();
                    } catch(SQLException ex) {
                        setTitle(ex.toString());
                    }
```

the line: "`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`" give me the next error:

`Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException`

if I remove that line the program runs fine but when I execute the action, it gives me the next exception:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\\LoginJava2\\myDB.sqlite`

That's weird because I'm using the same jar in both examples.

I'm using the next jar file: "`sqlitejdbc-v056`"

if someone could help me how to fix the error in the "line Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");"
or if I'm doing someting wrong in the URL connection... I will apreciate!!

Thanks and sorry for my english!!

Comment: Is the sqlLite `.jar` library in your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if someone clud help me how to fix the error in the "line Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");" or if I'm doing someting wrong in the URL connection... I will apreciate!!

The error message is telling you exactly what needs to be fixed -- you need to handle the exception that it mentions, the ClassNotFoundException.

The main thing you should notice is that catch blocks in your two code examples are different, and one works while the other doesn't. Note that I don't recommend that you use the first catch block, the one that catches Exception, even though it works, since catching all Exceptions is usually not a good idea and prevents exceptions that should percolate to a higher level from doing so. Instead you should catch the explicit Exceptions that need to be caught, here SQLException and ClassNotFoundException.

The [Exception Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) should help explain this more fully to you with code examples. How you catch this also will depend on if you're working with Java 1.7 or prior versions.

Comment: OK thanks... and what about the other error I have... I'm using the same JDBC in both examples, and just work fine in the first example!!

Comment: @user2268094: if your problem is due to the error message you posted, then I explained that in my answer. If there's another problem, then please elaborate.

Comment: I added another catch after the first, just like this: } catch(ClassNotFoundException){... and the error is fixed... now I have other problem, the information is not being saved in the data base!! Do you know why that's happening!?

Answer (score 0):

To Fix the problem I added the next to the code:

try {

```
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\LoginJava2\\myDB.sqlite");
                    Statement com = con.createStatement();
                    com.executeUpdate("insert into hell(username,pssword) " +
                            "values ('"+tfUname.getText()+"','"+tfUpass.getText()+"')");
                    con.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congrats, you have been registered succesfully");
                    RegisterWindow rw = new RegisterWindow();
                    rw.setVisible(false);
                    pack();
                    dispose();
                } catch(SQLException ex) {
                    setTitle(ex.toString());
                }
```

catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {      // I added this catch to handle the exception

```
                    setTitle(e.toString());
                }
```